# Tile Menu in Lightning Communities now has an "eye" overlay with Winter 19 release

Tags: community, community-builder

With the Winter 19 release Salesforce has added an "eye" to the Tile Menu overlay in Lightning Communities.  The eye shows up when you mouse over a tile.  I have created a Page Layout with CSS to remove the eye but was wondering if there was another way besides a new Page Layout?